# Bluetooth scan results increase with manual scan in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have implemented a broadcast receiver in Android to listen to all available Bluetooth signals. The receiver works, but only shows four devices. When I manually scan for devices in the android menu, I suddenly see eight different devices in my app.

How can I see all available devices without using manual scan?

code:

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            Log.d("bluetoothSignal", "name: "+ device.getName() + " adress: "+ device.getAddress() + "strength: "+ rssi + " Data: " + intent.getData());
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: I use the same BroadcastReceiver and it works for me, it shows all devices in area. Make sure your device is not paired while you run this code, because that lowers the bandwidth.

Comment: I get the idea that it has something to do with Bluetooth low energy devices, which I cannot automatically receive with this receiver. I am very sure I am not paired with any of the devices I am scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that in the 'android menu' scanning results can show the paired devices, as well as scanned devices. So this could account for the duplicates. This case however is not very likely because any good Bluetooth scanning results should prevent duplicate results but there may be special cases where duplicates could be allowed.

What I suspect is actually occurring is that the system settings is returning tradition Bluetooth Devices (using rfcomm) and Bluetooth LE devices. The problem is, most Bluetooth device menus don't show a identifier that indicates whether a device is tradition or Bluetooth LE device, just the device name. Furthermore, when using [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) it tends to prefer traditional Bluetooth Devices and only occasionally returns Bluetooth LE devices. For example in my experience, 85 percent of the time it does not discover Bluetooth LE devices in the time it takes to to complete a discovery process, 13 seconds. I recommend using a use both the traditional scanning mechanism and the Bluetooth LE scanning mechanism. To perform a Bluetooth LE scan get a reference to the [BluetoothLeScanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) get calling [BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()](http://getBluetoothLeScanner()). Once you have a reference, call [BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(ScanCallback callback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)). The ScanCallback will get fired with discovered Bluetooth LE devices that you can add to your ListView's adapter. Try this and see if you get similar results with the 'android menu'.